# Readraster cancelling written data

Tags: python, gdal, ogr

I am currently learning GIS in Python via libraries like GDAL etc. I am following the book Python Geospatial Development. In one of the exercises we create a raster filled with random numbers. However, when I then try to access it with the readraster method, it returns an array of zeroes. The exact code is:

for writing the raster:

```
from osgeo import gdal
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTIFF")
dstFile = driver.Create("Example Raster.tiff", 360, 180, 1,
gdal.GDT_Int16)

#specifying projection
from gdal import osr
spatialReference = osr.SpatialReference()
spatialReference.SetWellKnownGeogCS("WGS84")
dstFile.SetProjection(spatialReference.ExportToWkt())

#specifying georeferencing transform
originX = -180
originY = 90
cellWidth = 1.0
cellHeight = 1.0
dstFile.SetGeoTransform([originX, cellWidth, 0,
originY, 0, -cellHeight])

band = dstFile.GetRasterBand(1)

import random
values = []
for row in range(180):
    row_data = []
for col in range(360):
    row_data.append(random.randint(1, 100))
    values.append(row_data)

import struct
fmt = "<" + ("h" * band.XSize)
for row in range(180):
    scanline = struct.pack(fmt, *values[row])
    band.WriteRaster(0, row, 360, 1, scanline)
```

And then for reading the raster:

```
from osgeo import gdal
srcFile = gdal.Open("Example Raster.tiff")
band = srcFile.GetRasterBand(1)

import struct
fmt = "<" + ("h" * band.XSize)
for row in range(band.YSize):
    scanline = band.ReadRaster(0, row, band.XSize, 1,
                               band.XSize, 1,
                               band.DataType)
    row_data = struct.unpack(fmt, scanline)
print row_data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the dataset to flush the writes to file:

```
del band,  dstFile
```

See the "Saving and closing datasets/datasources"  section of the [GDAL Python Gotchas](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas):

> To save and close GDAL raster datasets or OGR vector datasources, the object needs to be dereferenced, such as setting it to None, a different value, or deleting the object. If there are more than one copies of the dataset or datasource object, then each copy needs to be dereferenced.
>
> The last dereference to the raster dataset writes the data modifications and closes the raster file. WriteArray(arr) does not write the array to disk, unless the GDAL block cache is full (typically 40 MB).